# Chrome Remote Desktop - PAM Authentication failure

Tags: google-chrome, remote-desktop

With my Chrome Remote Desktop installation, Remote Assistance works just fine.
However, Remote Connection fails with the error message: `The access code is invalid. Please try again`

- I run Ubuntu 16.04. Linux version 3.12.6 (root@BuildServer48-1) (gcc
  version 4.1.3 20070929 (prerelease) (Ubuntu 4.1.2-16ubuntu2)) #1 SMP
  Wed Jun 1 03:23:51 CST 2016
- I run Google-Chrome-Stable/stable, now 51.0.2704.84-1 amd64
- I run Chrome-Remote-Desktop_current_amd64.deb version 50.0.2661.22.

I am testing this both inside a LAN on the same subnet as well as from a remote site over the internet. I have two other windows machines on the same LAN configured with CRD as well, and everything works just fine with them.

Here are the last lines in the Chrome_Remote_Desktop Log:

```
2016-06-02 21:36:48,007:INFO:Host ready to receive connections.
[0602/213712:INFO:chromoting_host.cc(262)] Client connected: 3vipuf4wgjjkq@id.talk.google.com/chromoting4860B5C1
[0602/213717:INFO:pam_authorization_factory_posix.cc(128)] Local login check for admin failed.
[0602/213717:INFO:client_session.cc(337)] Client disconnected: 3vipuf4wgjjkq@id.talk.google.com/chromoting4860B5C1; error = 4
```

Anyone have any idea what could cause this, and how to fix it?